# htaccess re-direct rule fails

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On


RedirectMatch http://api.fuckedapps.com//app_dl.php?app_id=([0-9])$ http://fuckedapps.com/app_dl.php?app_id=$1
```

I am trying to redirect any url like this:

```
http://api.fuckedapps.com//app_dl.php?app_id=31
```

to this:

```
http://fuckedapps.com/app_dl.php?app_id=$1
```

Comment: `RedirectMatch` does not work with domain names -- it has to be URL (path part) only, e.g. `//app_dl.php?app_id=31`. For your case -- you need to use **mod_rewrite** to match domain name, url & query string (1 rule + 2 conditions).

Comment: I wish I knew how it was done

Comment: Have you escaped the dots? What happens, i. e. which error occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one (sorry, do not have Apache running here right now, so cannot test it on live system):

```
# Activate Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Actual rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =api.fuckedapps.com [NC]
RewriteCond ^/?app_dl\.php$ http://fuckedapps.com/app_dl.php [QSA,R=301,L]
```

I do not match query string, as it is the same on both ends, so I just use `QSA` flag to copy it unchanged.

Also -- consider using 302 redirect instead of 301 during testing (modern browsers do cache 301 redirects, so you may see wrong behaviour when rule is changed but browser still seems to be using old redirect) and change back to 301 after you are happy with results.

I'm just not sure about `//` in your original URL -- how Apache/mod_rewrite handles it exactly. But it should work fine.

BTW -- this means to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some modification may be required.

Comment: You do not need the QSA if there is no query string in the replacement URL. But you need a `NE` flag.

Comment: @SalmanA Why do I need `NE` flag? I do not provide any special characters in new URL. RE: `QSA` -- on setups that I have used so far (GoDaddy, my dev box (Apache under Windows)) I indeed have not needed to use it. But there were users who claimed that query string was not copied for them over to new URL on redirect and adding that flag helped -- whatever was the reason for it, but at the end of the day having it here does not hurt (in this particular instance).

Comment: `QSA` matters when there is a `?` specified in the target URL. Without `?`, original querystring is added to target URL whether or not QSA was specified (so yes, it won't hurt). With `?`, the specified querystring is used and original one is ignored. In this case, QSA flag tells mod_rewrite to append original querystring after the specified one.

Comment: and without `NE` mod_rewrite will double escape special characters in querystring; for example http://a.domain.com/a.php?foo=bar%20baz will redirect to http://b.domain.com/b.php?foo=bar%2520baz (notice how `%` became `%25`)

Comment: @SalmanA There is no need for `NE` flag in this particular example, even if original query string would have such special characters -- `QSA` takes care of it. It only required if you provide new query string manually.

Comment: Hmmm... sorry, I cannot verify it right now but I encourage you to give it a try; use original querystring that contains spaces.